# $wpdb Get count and order by count

Tags: sql, wordpress, count

I'm trying to create a leader board of the top 3 people that have entered things into the database, which will be part of my WordPress plugin.

Here is the table schema.

```
id    |    name    |    code

1          sam          456
2          craig        567
3          sam          456
4          sam          456
5          liam         321
6          liam         321
7          sam          456
```

and what I need is to get find out who has entered the most entries into the database and order by the highest in order to create a leader board. So using the above data the board would look like this:

```
position    |    name    |    entries

   1             sam            4
   2             liam           2
   3             craig          1
```

At the moment, I have this code:

```
global $wpdb;
$ck_af = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT name FROM wp_entry_log GROUP BY name ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 3")); 

$i = 1;
foreach($ck_af as $result) {
  echo "<tr><td> " . $result->name . "</td></tr>";
  $i++;
}
```

which outputs the results as:

```
sam
liam
craig
```

But I cannot seem to get the amount of times they are stored so I can display the entries.

**Can someone help me display the amount of times each entry is in the database whilst ordering and grouping them like they currently do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `COUNT` as part of the query.

Try the following:

```
global $wpdb;
$ck_af = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT name, COUNT(*) as `counter` FROM wp_entry_log GROUP BY name ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 3")); 

$i = 1;
foreach($ck_af as $result) {
  echo "<tr><td> " . $result->name . "</td><td> " . $result->counter. "</td></tr>";
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
global $wpdb;
$ck_af = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT rank() over (ORDER BY name) position, name, COUNT(*) as `counter` FROM wp_entry_log GROUP BY name ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 3")); 

$i = 1;
foreach($ck_af as $result) {
  echo "<tr><td> " . $result->name . "</td><td> " . $result->counter. "</td></tr>";
  $i++;
}
```